# PHP preg_replace not working as expected

Tags: preg-replace, str-replace

I'm trying to run a find replace of multiple values to do a mail merge effect on an HTML signature stored in the database.

I can get the string part replaced no worries, but for some reason it's leaving the "[" & "]" behind in the output.

Merge tags in the HTML would look like this: [FirstName], [LastName]

Original HTML would look like this:

**Kind regards**

**[FirstName] [LastName]**

After running the mailmerge function it should look like this:

**Kind regards**

**John Smith**

Here is what I've come up with so far, and Im sure the issue is something small:

```
public function merge_user_signature() {
    $user = $this->get_user_by_id();
    //spit_out($user);

    $authorisedMergeTags = array (
        "[FirstName]" => $user->firstName, 
        "[LastName]" => $user->lastName
    );

    $keys = array_keys($authorisedMergeTags);
    $values = array_values($authorisedMergeTags);
    $html = $this->get_user_signature();

    $mergedSignature = preg_replace($keys, array_values($authorisedMergeTags), $html);

    return $mergedSignature;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can't speak about that specific replace since I've not looked up the docs, however `[` and `]` are special characters in regex'es and should normally (if you want them to be used literally) be prefixed with backslash, as in `\[`.

Comment: First thing, you don't need a regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You don't need to use a regex to deal with literal strings** (whatever the situation):

```
return strtr($html, $authorisedMergeTags);
```